# How to embed image in SharePoint Workflow Association Form?

Tags: development, workflow, visual-studio, asp.net, resources

I am developing a custom SharePoint workflow in Visual Studio. I have a custom association form (ASPX) and I'd like to display an image, which is embedded into the project (and subsequently wsp).

I've tried all the standard Visual Studio methods for embedding an image in my SharePoint workflow project, but when trying to set the ImageUrl on asp:Image, the resource picker never shows my resource regardless of how I attempt to embed.

Comment: Answered my own question on StackOverflow copy of this question...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287924/how-to-embed-image-in-sharepoint-workflow-association-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287924/how-to-embed-image-in-sharepoint-workflow-association-form)...

Right click on the project > Add > 'SharePoint "Images' Mapped Folder', this creates a 'system' directory within the project where you can import your image resources.

These are then selectable using the resource explorer (which comes up when trying to set a field like ImageUrl).

Answer (score 0):

VS doesnt fullVSy recognize your paths in the SharePoint hive all the time. setting the url to /_layouts/yourfolder/image will work assuming your path is correct.